# tensorflow variables didn't initialize properly

Tags: tensorflow

Here I tried to create a simple model with one variable but the same across all the gpus. I tried to initialize the variable. However, I didn't get it initialized properly.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

def test_model(num):
    mu = 1.0
    sigma = 0.1
    with tf.variable_scope("same_on_all_gpu", reuse=True):
        var1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(1,1), mean = mu, stddev = sigma))
    return tf.add(var1, num)

with tf.device("/gpu:" + str(0)):
    with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % ("tower_gpu", 0)) as scope:
        ret0 = test_model([[0]])

with tf.device("/gpu:" + str(1)):
    with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % ("tower_gpu", 1)) as scope:
        ret1 = test_model([[1]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    r0, r1 = sess.run([ret0,ret1],{})
    print("r0 " + str(r0))
    print("r1 " + str(r1))
```

I got this output:

```
r0 [[ 0.]]
r1 [[ 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your code, but I think that when `test_model` returns, you leave the `same_on_all_gpu` scope that you used to create the variable.

Setting `reuse` equal to `True` in `tf.variable_scope` lets you access variables in the current scope and its sub-scopes, but you can't access a variable outside the current scope.